# Linux - mask in probe_irq_off useless?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, interrupt, drivers, probing

#### Context:

writing drivers for linux.

Source :
[free electrons - linux 4.x](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/irq/autoprobe.c#L158)

It seems that all the recent versions behave the same.

#### Question

Is the mask we pass to it (the "val" parameter) useless ? it seems unused in this function.

Thanks